# E488: Trailing characters error in VI with find and replace command

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, replace, find

I am trying a simple find and replace function in VI Editor to change a profile path but the `/` is getting in my way and I need a simple and clever solution.

I tried using:

```
%s/profile: "/fldr0/local/fldr/fldr1/profile/production/production.auto.profile"/profile: "/fldr0/local/fldr/fldr1/profile/development/development.auto.profile"/g
```

And got `E488: Trailing characters`.

I know it has to do with the slashes but not sure what a good workaround would be since I thought the `""` would take care of it but they didn't - any help appreciated! Read all the other threads and couldn't come up with a solution probably due to lack of brain power on my part

Answer (score 2):

You want to change instances of

```
profile: /fldr0/local/fldr/fldr1/profile/production/production.auto.profile
```

into

```
profile: /fldr0/local/fldr/fldr1/profile/development/development.auto.profile
```

One way is to use a different delimiter than `/` for the `:substitute` command,
i.e.:

```
%s;profile: /fldr0/local/fldr/fldr1/profile/production/production.auto.profile;profile: /fldr0/local/fldr/fldr1/profile/development/development.auto.profile;g
```

However, it can also be simplified quite alot:

```
%s/profile:.*\zsproduction\/production/development\/development/g
```

In the above regular expression, `profile:.*` will match the first part in
a greedy manner, up until the first `production`. `\zs` sets the start of the
matched part, which means everything before this is ignored for the
replacement. Finally, the `production/production` is the only part of the
string we want to change, and we escape the `/` with a backslash, i.e. `\/`.